# Comparing the id of two img tags onclick

Tags: javascript

I have created many images in a table. I want to display an alert dialogue if the two images have identical names. I will display `true` else `false`. I have written this code but when I click the first image it goes into the false case.

This is the code:

```
<script>
function changeImage1(){
    var img1 =document.getElementById("image_change");
    var img2 =document.getElementById("image_change1");
    if(img1==img2){
        alert("true");
    }else{
        alert("false");
    }
} 
</script>
```

Can anyone identify what is wrong?

Comment: it's normal, they don't have the same `id`, they are different, unless you want to check the `src` ? , try `img1.src === img2.src`

Answer (score 0):

They're different elements - if you want to check the `src` of each image, do this:

```
if (img1.src == img2.src) {...}
```